# How do I define a reducer at the top level?

Tags: ngrx

I have two reducer files that handle the two areas of state in my module...

```
export interface MyState {
  people: PeopleState;
  pets: PetState;
}

export const reducers: ActionReducerMap<MyState> = {
  people: peopleReducer,
  pets: petsReducer
};
```

This works fine.  However, I have some actions that need to update both areas of the state.  I'd like to handle this by having a reducer file that deals with things at the MyState level and can update people and pets.  I'd like to keep both the existing reducers that handle this at the lower levels.

I can't see how to register the top level reducer.  The way the code is now, any reducer added to the ActionReducerMap must be added as a property inside MyState rather than handling MyState as a whole.

Anyone got any ideas?

Thanks
Nick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that the only solution here is to use metaReducer, check this article: https://netbasal.com/implementing-a-meta-reducer-in-ngrx-store-4379d7e1020a

Description: metaReducer is a kind of reducer that stays above other reducers. It should have it's own actions, can have it's own effects. You can use it in such way:

```
export function metaReducer( reducer ) {
  return function reduce( state: ParentState, action: MetaReducerAction ) {
     switch(action.type)
        case PARENT_ACTION:
          return {
            ...state,
            people: peopleReducer(state.people, new DoSthWithPeople()),
            pets: petsReducer(state.pets, new DoSthWithPets())
          }
        default:
          return reducer(state, action);
  }
}
```

Where:

```
interface ParentState {
   pets: PetsState,
   people: PeopleState
}

type MetaReducerAction = ParentAction <-- this has type PARENT_ACTION
```

So the workflow is straight forward. In a place that you want a action to update both people and pets states, you need to dispatch PARENT_ACTION, then the actions DoSthWith... are going to be triggered on both slices of state. If you dispatch different action (the action of type that is not handled by the metaReducer, so sth different to PARENT_ACTION) then it will allow other reducers to handle the action (check whats in default section).

The last part is configuration, it should look like this:

```
StoreModule.forFeature(compose(metaReducer, combineReducers)(reducers))
```

Where reducers is just:

```
const reducers = {
   pets: petsReducer,
   people: peopleReducer
}
```

Edit: formatting

Comment: Checkout also: https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuringreducers/beyondcombinereducers

Comment: Thanks so much!  I'll try this.